# list is not updating when item is removed

Tags: python, json, django

I'm writing a service for my front-end to consume an update service which has the following payload shape.However, when i add some skills eg:["Custom, "Plumbing"] on my skill_sub_category everything works perfect, but when I'm trying to remove a skill on the skill_sub_category the list is not getting updated.This is how my payload to update a custom_item looks like

{
    "custom_items": 
    [
        { 
            "item_name": "item_custom",
            "item_type": 1 ,
            "measurement": "3m²" ,
            "skill_sub_category": ["Custom", "Plumbing","Carpet"],
            "price" : "80",
            "client": "OTHER", 
            "year":"2019",
            "items_source" : 0,
             "id": 582 }]}

My implementation looks like this.

```
   def update_items(self, request, params={}, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    :param request:
    :param params:
    :param args:
    :param kwargs:
    :return:
    """
    logger.debug("Entering the gate of the update items function")
    logger.debug("** Params are being used ** :%s" % params)
    # print(params)
    logger.debug("** Params to be updated ** :%s" % params)
    for custom in params['custom_items']:
        item_name = custom['item_name']
        item_type = str(custom['item_type'])
        item_type = ItemType.objects.get(pk=item_type)
        measurement = sanitize_data(custom['measurement'])
        # measurement = custom['measurement'].replace("", u"²")
        category = custom['skill_sub_category']
        # year = custom['year'] # Frontenders do not want us to send through the year. which makes since
        client = str(custom['client'])
        client = Client.objects.get(name=client)
        # year = PriceList.objects.get(year=year) #so we commented that
        fee = custom['price']
        items_source = custom['items_source']
        get_sp = self.staff
        logger.debug("**Fetching the Staff :%s" % get_sp)
        fetched_spp = get_sp.sp_id
        logger.debug("**Fetching the SP_id **:%s" % fetched_spp)
        try:
            item = Item.objects.get(pk=custom['id'], item_creator=fetched_spp)
        except Item.DoesNotExist:
            continue

        item.name = item_name
        item.item_type = item_type
        item.measurement = measurement
        item.items_source = items_source
        item.item_creator = fetched_spp
        item.activation_status = Item.ACTIVE
        item.is_custom_items = True
        item.save()
        price = item.price.first()
        price.client = client
        price.fee = fee
        # price.price_list = year     # And it's still working this way
        price.save()
        which_items_is_being_updated = Item.objects.get(pk=custom['id'])
        get_item_updated = which_items_is_being_updated.id
        logger.debug('**Item updated is ** :%s' % get_item_updated)
        print (which_items_is_being_updated)
        for skill in SkillSubCategory.objects.filter(name__in=category):
            skill.item.add(item)
    return {"success": True, "message": "Item updated successfuly"}
```

Everything else works fine expect when i'm updating the skill_sub_category by removing a skill. Can someone gives me a hint on how to solve  the issue when  a skill needs to be removed on the skill_sub_category list ?

Comment: And where exactly is the element being removed?

Comment: you mean on my payload ? so when i'm trying to remove one item on the skill_sub_category list for instance on skill_sub_category": ["Custom", "Plumbing","Carpet"]  if user want to remove carpet from the list so the skill_sub_category should become ["Custom", "Plumbing"], however it's not updating

Comment: Where do you believe you are removing an item from a list? What list? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Im removing items on this list  "skill_sub_category": ["Custom", "Plumbing","Carpet"]. This is stored on my model skill_sub category  which looks like this         class SkillSubCategory(models.Model):
                                      name = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='')

Comment: *Where* are you doing that?

Comment: Ok so when im trying to remove one skill manually in postman  ... i'm sending the request using postman. 

I'm writing a service for my front-end to consume an update service which has the following payload shape.However, when i add some skills eg:["Custom, "Plumbing"] on my skill_sub_category everything works perfect, but when I'm trying to remove a skill on the skill_sub_category the list is not getting updated.This is how my payload to update a custom_item looks like

{ "custom_items": [ { "item_name": "item_custom", "skill_sub_category": ["Custom", "Plumbing","Carpet"] }]}

Comment: @DanielRoseman   so i am precisely updating the  category  = custom['skill_sub_category']  which  holds my list of skills